# Xampp Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in line 0

Tags: php, windows-7, xampp

I have installed Xampp on windows 7. When I try to run code I get the error

> Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in line 0

This is the same code I have run on the pc before, all I have done is reinstalled Win 7 and a clean install of XAMPP

Answer (score 109):

You seem to have the line

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

twice in your php.ini file and/or subfiles.

You need to find all relevant php.ini files in your xampp directory and remove or comment out one of the module directives like this:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

After a server restart, this should solve it.

Comment: Thanks I have found one entry in Dynamic Extensions and one in
Module Settings - which is the best disable

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem while installing composer as well.

Comment: Does not work, I searched all occurences by using notepad++. Even If I delete ALL occurences, then I get this error, even after restarting the webserver.

Comment: It's really odd as I had the same issue but no duplication of `extension=php_openssl.dll` anywhere in the .ini file

Comment: This fixed it for me, I had two entries and I commented them out and restarted apache. and also restarted my terminal to make sure it wouldn't cache.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the first solution, and it worked.

Answer (score 32):

1. Open xampp -> PHP -> php.ini
2. Open the file *php.ini* in any text editor
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and Search for *openssl*
4. Comment the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` by placing a semi-colon at the beginning: `;extension=php_openssl.dll`

Note : If you want to enable it again remove the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

This warning message is indicating that the *OpenSSL* module is being loaded more than *once* in your PHP configuration.

- Open `php.ini` file
- Find the another OpenSSL word and comment it by adding `;` at the beginning
- Save file
- And restart Apache.

Here's the Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and there were not multiple `extension=php_openssl.dll` in my case. The reason was because I had two copies of apache for some reasons, but I only used one.

I deleted the copy and changed the environment variable `Path` and `OPENSSL_CONF` to point to the correct webserver.

After restarting the webserver it worked!
Make sure to restart all terminals and CMDs, otherwise the old environment variables are used and the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall the xampp and give new location to the required bar in composor installation.