# PHP Settings Error: Composer will not work with your current setting

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install Laravel, for that while installing Composer I am getting the problem mentioned below.

```
 The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
 C:\xampp\php\php.exe

 The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

 A duplicate setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem.

 Program Output:
 Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Please post your php.ini located at C:\xampp\php\php.ini over here: http://pastebin.com/ and share the link with us

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675348/xamp-warning-module-openssl-already-loaded-in-line-0) question?

Comment: @Wouter Rutgers Ya Sure, http://pastebin.com/PUGx4Y5V/?e=1

Comment: @aleksejjj I saw this and tried, but in my php.ini it is already as 'extension=php_openssl.dll'

Comment: You have this line twice. You need comment it and leave only 1

Comment: You need to remove line 876

Comment: Ok ok..sure, Hope that is the problem causing line??

Comment: Thanks!! aleksejjj, It works perfect

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how it got there, but you had the rule `extension=php_openssl.dll` twice in your configuration.

I've uploaded a fixed version where I removed the second `extension=` line here: http://pastebin.com/gtU8unAX