# Composer setup installation error

Tags: php, composer-php, failed-installation, php-ini

I'm trying to install Composer on Windows 7 and XAMPP, but getting those errors/messages when run installation setup.

> The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
>   C:\xampp\php\php.exe
>
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>
> A duplicate setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem.
>
> Program Output: Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on
>   line 0

I have been googled for while, but could not find proper solution or anything related to this. Closest thing was to remove comment openssl extension in php.ini file, but did not worked for me. To be clear I have very basic understanding of server tweaking.

Comment: OpenSSL is being loaded twice. Look in your php.ini above to see openssl.dll, and comment it out in one of the places.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Both of them were commented out, one in Dynamic Extensions, another one in Module Settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Composer - Internal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913142/installing-composer-internal-error)

Comment: your solution sits here : [Comment one of openssl extension entries in php.ini][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675348/xamp-warning-module-openssl-already-loaded-in-line-0

Comment: @CagCak Thank you for your response. The problem has been solved by Farkie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> > OpenSSL is being loaded twice. Look in your php.ini above to see
> >     openssl.dll, and comment it out in one of the places.
>
> – Farkie

Answer (score 23):

I guess this is a problem which had been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763452/composer-not-install-in-windows-7/42577587#42577587) you can follow the solution or go to the below link whichever if you want.

I figured it out and successfully installed Composer in My windows 10 PC.

**There are some steps you have to follow in order to solve your problem.**

**1st solution.**

1. Find and Open `php.ini` located in your "php" folder In my case it is in xampp the file is in `c:\xampp\php\`
2. Find `"extension=php_openssl.dll"`
3. `";extension=php_openssl.dll"`  **uncomment by removing the semicolon** `";"`
4. Restart your xampp , now extension should be loaded after that.
5. Try again now you are able to install composer.

**2nd solution(If the above solution not work for you then go with below solution . )**

**This works in my case**

1. Find and Open `php.ini` located in your "php" folder In my case it is in xampp the file is in `c:\xampp\php\`
2. Open SHELL from Xampp start panel by clicking on shell button.
3. Write `php` in shell and hit enter
4. If you get some waring message in your shell something like below .
   [image]
5. Then you have to fix these waring message by commenting all these extension in your `php.ini` file.(Actually cause of these warning messages are because more than one times that extension are enabled or you can say **un-commented** in `php.ini` file).

   **For Example which is in my case.**

   a). You can see in above image there is warning message for curl.

   ```
   Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 .
   ```

   b) To fix this find `php_curl.dll` file in your `php.ini` file and **comment that extension by adding semicolon** `";"` in front of that extension like this `;extension=php_curl.dll`

Follow above steps if you have more than one warning for each extension untill you are not getting any warning message in your shell.

6. Restart your xampp , now extension should be loaded after that.
7. Try again now you are able to install composer.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question

Comment: Thank you for your response, the first comment  above solved my problem.

Comment: @gorans93 @ You're welcome , as of now your problem is solved please mark it as solved and give thumbs up for the solutions . Happy coding !!! (amitamie.com) :-) ;-)

Comment: I also fixed same issue. Thank you very much for all contributors...

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to your xampp\php\php.ini
2. Press ctrl+f to find extension_dir and change its relative path to
   absolute path e.g from extension_dir="\ext" to
   extension_dir="E:\xampp\php\ext"
3. Press ctrl+f to find browscap and change its path e.g from
   browscap="\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini" to
   browscap="E:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
4. Save the file and restart the xampp

try again with the composer installer

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of google indexing,

I write the error I had

If Composer doesn't install in windows 7, 8, 10 with php provided in the xampp installation with this error message

***The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly***: 
*yourPathTo\php.exe*

***The program failed to run correctly. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. Make sure you have installed the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable.***

The Composer message really confused me for the part of Visual C++, in fact it was not the case

Well, after long searches, I finally have found the Sarim' solution that you find in this same thread
[Composer setup installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489614/composer-setup-installation-error/59037305#59037305)

This specific issue is due to the php.ini which is default provided by the xampp installation which as highlighted by Sarim, does have paths relative to xampp installation and won't allow Composer-Setup.exe to properly run.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a composer and you need to update it, you can use this command line :

```
composer self-update
```

This working for me.

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you were following how to install php guide such as [this one](https://www.w3resource.com/php/installation/install-php-on-windows.php) it directs you to uncomment the `extension_dir = [to your installation folder]`. then if you install Composer it will give you the complaint.

Solution : comment the `extension_dir` line in you php.ini file and continue with your installation