# laravel 5 : Error running php artisan php.exe

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to run php artisan in terminal, i got error php program, and i try composer update and didn't work, how to fix this error ?

```
Program 'php.exe' failed to run: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another processAt line:1 char:1
+ php artisan
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ php artisan
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: It seems you opened your file in any other thing like code editor etc.

Comment: @Sunderam i don't open it in any other code editor, yesterday i running php artisan work normally, but today my php artisan error

Answer (score 0):

> you can get an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489614/composer-setup-installation-error) at StackOverflow

in short, you can try this answer .to more visit [given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489614/composer-setup-installation-error) StackOverflow link

> OpenSSL is being loaded twice. Look in your php.ini above to see
> openssl.dll, and comment it out in one of the places.

– Farkie