# I'm trying to install Composer on Windows 10 , but getting those errors/messages when run installation setup

Tags: php, composer-php

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\php\php.ini

I have been googled for while, but could not find proper solution or anything related to this.

Comment: That's not an error, just a notice. If there are no errors in the output, check for errors in Windows log.

Comment: does not allow to install

Comment: Check out this solution
[composer-setup-installation-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489614/composer-setup-installation-error)